# Why is there a click after I compress the wav?

Tags: c, audio, compression, mp3, wav

I'm using freemp3droid to convert wav files into mp3s. There is a click at the beginning of the file. When I take a look at the file in audacity, the initial 100bytes (beyond the header) have the same pattern. What could be happening??

Here is the waveform of the click (it is the 99% identical,EVERY single time)

[image]

http://code.google.com/p/freemp3fordroid/source/browse/trunk/jni/frontend/main.c#215

Comment: Did you open a bug report on the website?

Comment: I don't know what you meant by: *there is a click at the beginning of the file*

Comment: karl, there should be silence. But EVERY compression has a click in it that was NOT recorded, it was generated by some logical bug in the compression process.

Comment: Have you tried using a different MP3 encoder?

Comment: Its not about using a different one. Its about fixing this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is worth understanding what the click is.  If you in fact compressed the header, you are getting a weird discontinuous signal to start with.  You have to understand a bit about signals to realize what is happening.  Your waveform does not start with a zero value.  That means that you instantaneously have to get from no voltage to some voltage.  If you had a sine wave starting with zero,  you would hear a pure tone.  Since you start with a signal, that is the equivalent of a high frequency squeak at the start, which your speakers turn into a pop.

You will get the same pop if you compress a signal that doesn't start with zero.

The way to stop this is to add a rampup to start your sound.  Start with zero and linearly ramp up until you get to the starting value of your wave, and you won't get a pop sound.

Answer (score 2):

Is your encoder trying to compress the WAV/RIFF 44 byte header as if it were audio?

Comment: Ive tried both, compressing with the 44 bytes, and without, and both have the pop.

Comment: FYI, the encoder is open source, there is a link to the source code in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see a really issue here. Because, lossy compressions generally use continues functions to approximate input data. In MP3 case, Modified Cosine Discrete Transform is used which includes several cosine functions with different set of parameters (take a look at [Fourier Series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_Series) for understanding the basic concepts). As a result, you can't represent high frequency easily with such approaches and those causes high peaks or some distortion at some points.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late but the correct answer is, *freemp3droid* is not and never was able to encode any other format than raw pcm. Since your input format was wav, *freemp3droid* interpretes the wav header as signal and thus produces as huge initial click.

The sentence *"convertFile: the raw pcm or wav data to convert to MP3"* at http://code.google.com/p/freemp3fordroid is simply wrong.